# How Can I Solve Qt C++ SIGSEV Error Problem?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I'm building a simple GUI phonebook application using Qt and I am stuck. 
I have 3 classes: contacts, editcontact, and newcontact.

Contacts.h

```
class Contacts : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Contacts(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~Contacts();
    void save_contact(std::string name, long long phone, std::string email);
    void edit_contact(std::string name, long long phone, std::string email);

private:
    Ui::Contacts *ui;
    std::map<std::string, Person> phonebook;

};
#endif // CONTACTS_H
```

NewContact.h

```
class NewContact : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:

    explicit NewContact(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    void save_details();
    ~NewContact();

private slots:
    void on_save_button_clicked();
    void on_cancel_button_clicked();

private:
    Ui::NewContact *ui;
    Contacts *contact;

};
```

newcontact.cpp

```
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QDoubleValidator>
#include <iostream>

#include "newcontact.h"
#include "ui_newcontact.h"
#include "data_store.h"
#include "person.h"

NewContact::NewContact(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::NewContact)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->phone_edit->setValidator( new QDoubleValidator(0, 100, 2, this) );
}

void NewContact::save_details()
{
    std::string name;
    long long phone;
    std::string email;
    if(!(ui->phone_edit->text().isEmpty())){
         /* Phone field cannot be empty.
          * If it is, prompt the user to input a phone number
         */
         if((ui->name_edit->text().isEmpty())){              /*If name field is empty, use the phone number as the name key*/
             name = ui->phone_edit->text().toStdString();
         }else{
             name = ui->name_edit->text().toStdString();
         }
         to_camel_case(name);
         std::string p = ui->phone_edit->text().toStdString();
         phone = std::stoll(p);
         email = ui->email_edit->text().toStdString();

        contact->save_contact(name, phone, email);
        close();

     }else{
         QMessageBox::critical(this,"Can't Do It!", "Phone Field Cannot Be Empty!");

     }
}

NewContact::~NewContact()
{

    delete ui;
}
```

EditContact.h

```
class editcontact : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit editcontact(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~editcontact();
    void add_contact(std::string name, long long phone, std::string email);

private slots:
    void on_save_button_clicked();
    void on_cancel_button_clicked();

private:
    void fill_data();
private:
    Ui::editcontact *ui;
    Contacts *contact;
    QString name{contact->current_name()};
};
```

editcontact.cpp

```
#include "editcontact.h"
#include "ui_editcontact.h"
#include "contacts.h"

#include <QDoubleValidator>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <algorithm>

editcontact::editcontact(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::editcontact)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->phone_edit->setValidator( new QDoubleValidator(0, 100, 2, this) );
    fill_data();
}

editcontact::~editcontact()
{
    delete ui;
}

void editcontact::add_contact(std::string name, long long phone, std::string email)
{
    contact->save_contact(name, phone, email);
}

void editcontact::fill_data()
{
    QString ph, mail;
    ui->name_edit->setText(name);
    std::string p = name.toStdString();                                    //Convert name to std::string from Qstring, the key is an std::string
    ph = QString::fromStdString(std::to_string(contact->get_phone(p)));        //Convert phone number to QString
    mail = QString::fromStdString(contact->get_email(p));

    ui->phone_edit->setText(ph);
    ui->email_edit->setText(mail);

}

void editcontact::on_save_button_clicked()
{
   std::string key = ui->name_edit->text().toStdString();
   long long phone = ui->phone_edit->text().toULongLong();
   std::string email = ui->email_edit->text().toStdString();

   contact->edit_contact(key, phone, email);

   QMessageBox::information(this,"Success", "Contact change successful!",QMessageBox::Ok);
   close();
}

void editcontact::on_cancel_button_clicked()
{
    close();
}
```

Problem is, I can do

```
void EditContact::add_contact(std::string name, long long phone, std::string email)
{
    contact_edit->save_contact(name, phone, email);
}
```

Everything runs fine.

But when I run

```
void NewContact::save_details()
{
    std::string name;
    long long phone;
    std::string email;  

    contact_add->save_contact(name, phone, email);
    close(); 
}
```

The program suddenly crashes. I used Qt debug and it says I have a SIGSEV error, and I read that this could be a pointer problem. I don't know how to fix it.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please show the code that you're actually executing. Those last 2 code examples are not valid C++.

Comment: If you run your app with the debugger, it will stop where the exception is raised. Check if you didn't forget to initialize one of your attributes.

Comment: Yes, it does. I just don't know how to fix it. I think it has to do with the pointer to Contacts

Comment: @Darhuuk I just edited to show the code

Comment: Why are you using a pointer to Contacts?  Where did you allocate memory for it? Your code is currently not a [mcve]. The bug is in code you don't show.

Comment: Could you tell me what to do, please?

Comment: Start by addressing the questions in my comment. No one can help with the code that they don't see.

Comment: In the code shown you use both `NewContact::contact` and `editcontact::contact` but neither is ever initialized.

Comment: We still don't know when, where or how `contact_add` or `contact_edit` were assigned.

Comment: The bug is what @G.M. said you never initialized `NewContact::contact` or `editcontact::contact`. because these are pointers and they are not initialized you can't use them. You can't call `fill_data();` from `editcontact::editcontact(QWidget *parent)` while `contact` is not initialized. Do you really want `contact` to be a pointer making it a pointer seems to serve no purpose and just makes the code more difficult to get correct.

Comment: @drescherjm yes, how to initialize it or use it is what I'm trying to figure out. How do I do that, please?

Comment: You can use new in your constructor similar to how you wrote `ui(new Ui::editcontact)`. But then you have to remember to delete the pointer in your destructor. Again its better not do this and change `Contacts *contact;` to `Contacts contact;` and fix the code to use `contact.` everywhere you use `contact->`

Comment: @drescherjm I have tried both suggestions. Both work fine but the data I want does not get inserted into the map in Contacts. When I use pointers, just the way it is in the code, then the data gets inserted into the std::map for EditContacts but crashes for NewContacts.

Comment: `QString name{contact->current_name()};` is also a bug. This code executes before the current is initialized. And even if it did not the `current_name()` would be empty in the constructor.